# Permission on the main folder isn't reflected on the sub folders

Tags: permissions, chmod, executable

I have assigned a folder(MF) to a group (ENG). This group has read, wright and execute permissions to the folder MF. However, MF has sub folders in it. Some sub folders do not list the ENG group to have executable permissions. Those folders have root as group. I have some permissions issue because of this.

Comment: Ownership and permissions can be set differently for each file and directory. The owner of a file (or directory) can change these settings. Use `chmod` with the `-R` flag to change permissions recursively in a directory, or `chown -R` to change ownership of a directory and all objects in it.